# Inner join column twice with different values

Tags: mysql

I am new to database design so if this is an inefficient design, please let me know. This is my first post here and if you have any tips on how I could describe it better, I would appreciate it.

The situation is as follows:

- Users register and are able to review other users
- I have a table "Users"
- I have a table "Reviews"

The review table has the following columns:

- ReviewID
- UserID (of the person who wrote the review)
- Review: The actual review in text
- Reviewed_User_ID: The UserID of the person who got reviewed

My question is: How would I go about creating a join that displays the columns: Users.First_name, Review.review, first_name of reviewed person

It will then read like: Name - wrote review about - Name. Instead of Name - wrote review about - UserID

The inner join like this:

```
SELECT users.first_name, review.review, review.reviewed_user_id
FROM users
INNER JOIN review ON users.user_id = review.user_ID
```

Will show me the reviewed_user_id but I would like to add the first_name of that person aswell. Is this even possible?

Many thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Comment: When you need to `JOIN` more than once with the same table - just use different table aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use something like that

```
SELECT users.first_name
,      review.review
,      review.reviewed_user_id
,      reviewed_user.first_name
FROM   users
       INNER JOIN review ON users.user_id = review.user_ID
       INNER JOIN users reviewed_user ON review.reviewed_user_id = reviewed_user.user_id
```

in this case we add other join to table `users` from table `review` by field `reviewed_user_id` with alias `reviewed_user`

Comment: Many, many thanks MegaTron. This has answered my question and you have taught me something new!